# how to avoid creating empty csv from web site web scraping?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

here is my code, it works fine I can take all data from cite that I need
But the problem is to avoid creating empty csv's. My code checks all pages from the site and stores them into csv. So while it does that I am getting a lot of empty csv's because the info that I am trying to get is not on that page, so is it possible to create only those csv's that have a text in it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


for i in range(1, 11001):

    page_sc = requests.get('https://www.rlsnet.ru/mkb_index_id_{}.htm'.format(i))

    soup_sc = BeautifulSoup(page_sc.content, 'html.parser')
    syns = soup_sc.find_all(id='synonyms')
    syn_sc = [syn.find(class_='block').get_text() for syn in syns]

    items_sc = soup_sc.find_all(class_='subcatlist__item')
    mkb_names_sc = [item_sc.find(class_='subcatlist__link').get_text() for item_sc in items_sc]


    mkb_stuff_sce = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'first': mkb_names_sc,

        })
    syn_stuff_sce = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'syn': syn_sc,
        }
    )

    print(mkb_stuff_sce)
    print(syn_stuff_sce)
    syn_stuff_sce.to_csv('/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/Python/CSV/syn{}.csv'.format(i))
    mkb_stuff_sce.to_csv('/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/Python/CSV/mkb{}.csv'.format(i))
```

for example I have 5 csv files 3 of them are with data that I need other two I don't need at all so how can I ignore them in code and create only csv's with data.

Comment: you can check if `syn_sc` and/or `mkb_names_sc` are empty. if not, create a dataframe and save it to csv

Comment: @luigigi yes I know but how can do that in code/sorry I am new in python

Comment: @George, Are `syn_stuff_sce` and `mkb_stuff_sce` treated as one related group? Could they be saved separately?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes I am saving them separatly. they are in different group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


for i in range(1, 11001):

    page_sc = requests.get('https://www.rlsnet.ru/mkb_index_id_{}.htm'.format(i))

    soup_sc = BeautifulSoup(page_sc.content, 'html.parser')
    syns = soup_sc.find_all(id='synonyms')
    syn_sc = [syn.find(class_='block').get_text() for syn in syns]

    items_sc = soup_sc.find_all(class_='subcatlist__item')
    mkb_names_sc = [item_sc.find(class_='subcatlist__link').get_text() for item_sc in items_sc]

    if mkb_names_sc:
        mkb_stuff_sce = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                'first': mkb_names_sc,

            })
        print(mkb_stuff_sce)
        mkb_stuff_sce.to_csv('/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/Python/CSV/mkb{}.csv'.format(i))

    if syn_sc:
        syn_stuff_sce = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                'syn': syn_sc,
            }
        )
        print(syn_stuff_sce)
        syn_stuff_sce.to_csv('/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/Python/CSV/syn{}.csv'.format(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if a dataframe is empty

```
if mkb_stuff_sce.empty:
    pass
    #or log this somewhere if you need to
else:
    mkb_stuff_sce.to_csv()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `if` block to write csv only if dataframe is not empty, like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


for i in range(1, 11001):

    page_sc = requests.get('https://www.rlsnet.ru/mkb_index_id_{}.htm'.format(i))

    soup_sc = BeautifulSoup(page_sc.content, 'html.parser')
    syns = soup_sc.find_all(id='synonyms')
    syn_sc = [syn.find(class_='block').get_text() for syn in syns]

    items_sc = soup_sc.find_all(class_='subcatlist__item')
    mkb_names_sc = [item_sc.find(class_='subcatlist__link').get_text() for item_sc in items_sc]


    mkb_stuff_sce = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'first': mkb_names_sc,

        })
    syn_stuff_sce = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'syn': syn_sc,
        }
    )

    print(mkb_stuff_sce)
    print(syn_stuff_sce)

    if(!syn_stuff_sce.empty):
        syn_stuff_sce.to_csv('/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/Python/CSV/syn{}.csv'.format(i))

    if(!mkb_stuff_sce.empty):
        mkb_stuff_sce.to_csv('/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/Python/CSV/mkb{}.csv'.format(i))
```

Comment: Is it possible to separate the line of syn_stuff_sce.to_csv

with the coma they are separated with space. Where I need comma

Comment: of course you can. you should take a look at the `pd.to_csv` documentation